# Why does the elementary measure not obey translation invariance?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm going through Terence Tao's 'Introduction to Measure theory', and on page 6, he says that the following definition of a measure for an arbitrary set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ does not obey translation invariance:
$$m(E):=\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N^d}|(E \cap \frac{1}{N} \mathbb{Z}^d)|$$
The example he uses is if $d=1$, and $E:=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$, saying that this definition would give $E$ a measure of $1$, but give the translate $E+\sqrt{2}$ a measure of zero. I don't understand how these separate measures are obtained, and what the limit is in each case.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that you have to look at points of the form $x=1/N$. There are exactly $N+1$ of those points in $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ (for $N=2:$ $0/2, 1/2, 2/2$, for $N=3:$ $0,1/3, 2/3, 3/3$ and  so on). Then, the given limit is just
$$
\lim\frac{N+1}{N}=1.
$$
On the other hand, if you shift the rationals by an irrational amount like $\sqrt{2}$, they all become irrational and there is no intersection with the numbers of the form $k/N$ for any $N$. Therefore, the limit is zero.